# Finger and Blob Touch Inputs not recognised when Tagged Object is on Samsung SUR40 table

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

So, basically I filter touch inputs to only recognise Finger and Tag touches from every screen except for the Training Screen where I recognise Finger, Tag and Blob touches. I do this by overriding the OnPreviewTouchDown(TouchEventArgs e) method in MainWindow which is a SurfaceWindow. See code below for override method.

```
    protected override void OnPreviewTouchDown(TouchEventArgs e)
    {

        bool isFinger = e.TouchDevice.GetIsFingerRecognized();
        bool isTag = e.TouchDevice.GetIsTagRecognized();
        //Allows all touches on Train Screen. Only fingers and tags everywhere else
        if (e.Source.ToString() != "dtt_app.TrainScreen")
        {
            if (isFinger == false && isTag == false)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
       base.OnPreviewTouchDown(e);
    }
```

This is what my Token Visualisation code looks like

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TagVisualizationDefinition TokenTagDef =
                    new TagVisualizationDefinition();
            // The tag value that this definition will respond to.
            TokenTagDef.Value = i;
            // The .xaml file for the UI
            TokenTagDef.Source =
                new Uri("TokenVisualization.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            // The maximum number for this tag value.
            TokenTagDef.MaxCount = 100;
            // Orientation offset (default).
            TokenTagDef.OrientationOffsetFromTag = 0.0;
            // Physical offset (horizontal inches, vertical inches).
            TokenTagDef.PhysicalCenterOffsetFromTag = new Vector(0.0, 0.0);
            // Tag removal behavior (default).
            TokenTagDef.TagRemovedBehavior = TagRemovedBehavior.Fade;
            // Orient UI to tag? (default).
            TokenTagDef.UsesTagOrientation = true;

            // Add the definition to the collection.
            MyTagVisualizer.Definitions.Add(TokenTagDef);

        }
```

And this is the XAML code for the TrainScreen which is a UserControl that is set as the content of MainWindow

```
<UserControl x:Class="dtt_app.TrainScreen"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <s:TagVisualizer
            Name="MyTagVisualizer" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Transparent" 
            Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
            VisualizationAdded="OnVisualizationAdded">

        <Canvas Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=topWindow, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=topWindow, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Label Width ="500" Canvas.Top="100" Content="Label" Name="Instruction" FontSize="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Popup Name="Positive" Width="240" Height="200" Placement="MousePoint" AllowsTransparency="True" IsEnabled="True" IsOpen="False">
            <Image Source="images/SmileyFace.png">
            </Image>
        </Popup>
        <Popup Name="Negative" Width="240" Height="200" Placement="MousePoint" IsEnabled="True" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="False">
            <Image Source="images/SadFace.png">
            </Image>
        </Popup>
    </Canvas>
    </s:TagVisualizer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have no idea why any touch input is just not recognised whenever a tagged object is on the table. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Please. I've exhausted every possibility, and I really need to figure this out since time is running out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that input is hit testing to your tagvisualization (you didnt show us the code for that).  Remember that "Transparent" *is* hit tested (use Background=null or IsHitTestVisible=false to make something not hit test)

You can confirm it's not a hardware/platform problem by running the Input Visualizer tool.